# ThinkPad T420s docking station: no sound on external speakers

Tags: sound, thinkpad, alsa, hda-intel

When I plug external speakers into the docking station for Thinkpad T420s i get no sound (internal speakers mute).

P.S. I know the solution but it seems to be ok post problem specific solution in form of question and answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to add line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad
```

to the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.

After that you have to reload alsa:

```
killall pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
pulseaudio -D
```

This can be applicable on other thinkpad laptops.

You can also try different models (see HdaIntelSoundHowto at help.ubuntu.com).

If this method doesn't help you can to try to debug hda-intel using [HDA Analyzer](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer). 
For example for my laptop I could use:

```
/usr/local/bin/hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01c SET_PIN_WIDGET_CONTROL 0x40
```

to enable sound on external speakers. But it is not very good solution since you have to do it manually each time you plug external speakers.

hda-verb program can be downloaded from ftp://ftp.suse.com/pub/people/tiwai/misc/hda-verb-0.3.tar.gz.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with a Lenovo 90W ultra dock and X240:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo-dock
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem.

The correct option to pass to `snd-hda-intel` is `tp410`, as referenced [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/sound/pci/hda/patch_conexant.c#L976) in the Linux kernel.

A file under `/etc/modprobe.d/` ending in `.conf` should contain

```
options snd-hda-intel model=tp410
```

(don't forget to check for existing entries)