# ThinkPad W540 docking station: no sound on external speakers

Tags: thinkpad

When I plug headphones into the headphone jack in Ultra Dock on my W540, I don't have any sound.

I have tried the proposed solutions for T420s mentioned in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82363/thinkpad-t420s-docking-station-no-sound-on-external-speakers) , none of them worked for W540.

Is there a way to make the external headphone jack on the Ultra Dock work with Ubuntu? I have 15.04 with kernel 3.19.0-26.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: Use HDAJackRetask tool from alsa-tools-gui package.

1. Install alsa-tools-gui package that contains `HDAJackRetask`.

   `sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui`
2. Launch `hdajackretask` from the command line or unity launcher
3. From the drop-down menu at the top, choose `Realtek ALC3232` as the codec.
4. Check `show unconnected pins` and `Advanced override` options from the right sidebar.
5. Look for the entry with `Pin ID: 0x16` and check Override.
   [image]
6. Use the following options for overriding:

   - Connectivity: Jack
   - Location: External
   - Device: Headphone
   - Jack: 3.5 mm
   - Color: Green
   - Jack Detection: Not present
   - Channel group: 3
   - Channel (in group): Front
7. Click **Apply now** to test new settings.
8. Finally after making sure it works, you may persist the settings by clicking **Install boot override**. This will make sure your settings will be loaded with every boot.

Comment: Thanks for posting, this worked beautifully.

Though I thought I might mention that I tried using "Jack Detection: Present" and that seems to work. Detection appears to work fine and it lets me switch to internal speakers automatically.

Comment: This worked with my Lenovo Thinkpad W541 running Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 and it's Ultra Dock. Like @Fozefy I set "Jack Detection" to "Present" and everything worked fine (though I'm not sure what it does). Following these instructions I'm able to use the dock's jack, the laptop's jack or the builtin speakers all depending on where my headphones are plugged in (without doing anything in Ubuntu).

Comment: It looks like the [boot override is done](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-tools.git;a=blob;f=hdajackretask/apply-changes.c;h=aa291ce2d86eb3f86146d9a415dbd4a0196c3aba;hb=HEAD#l36) by setting values in files like `/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/modulename`, `/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/hints` and `/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs` if one wanted to try to do this with config management instead of manually with the `hdajackretask` UI